# Delay with Internet Explorer noticing changes to location.hash

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This may be common knowledge, but I can't seem to find anything out there regarding the issue.  Here's a little background:

I have some pages that use Bootstrap's tabbing system.  In the `$(document).ready()` function for these pages is some basic code that activates a tab based on the hash in the URL, and a short function that attaches to the tabs' shown function that changes the location's hash with `location.replace`.  The result is that you can link to a specific tag and also refreshing the page keeps you on the current tab.  This works fine in everything but Internet Explorer.

In Internet Explorer (I've been testing with IE9), there seems to be a delay (about 10-15 seconds) before IE recognizes that the location hash has changed.  A similar thing happens when typing the hash manually into the address bar and loading the page--it takes a couple of refreshes to recognize.  Clicking links with the hash embedded in them seems to load fine.

I'm assuming this is some kind of glitch.  I suppose I could just attach a cookie to the code that handles persisting tab state, but has anyone else found a more elegant way of handling this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with or aware of any delays in the Bootstrap's tabbing system, you may want to verify the issue is not due to your specific use or computer. I haven’t been able to produce any delays using the jQuery hashchange plugin on any of the browsers I'm familiar with.

As far as other ways of handling hash based navigation, I wrote the following to change content/pages on hashchange events using the jQuery hashchange plugin; mainly to cleanly support back/forward/links with hashes.  I following is a trimmed version of what I’m using.

The example provides an anchor link as well as generated  with onclick events.  Using onclick events is preferred because if a user clicks a currently active tab, the page is still reloaded.  Page load times are tracked to make sure a page isn’t loaded twice within 100ms.

jQuery hash plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/jquery.ba-hashchange.js"></script>
<script>
var hashUris = [];
var tabSet;
var actPage = '';
// bare tab array (use to populate tab html and hash array)
tabSet = [{hash: 'page1', pageId:1, id: 1}, {hash: 'page10', pageId:10, id:2 }, {hash: 'page20' , pageId: 20, id: 3}];

// handles the hash events
$(function() {
    // loop all tab array, add items to hash array, determine primary page and active page
    $.each(tabSet, function(i, tab) {
        // using tabIndex to prevent looping hash array later
        tab.tabIndex = i;
        // first tab is primary by default
        if (typeof priTabId == 'undefined') priTabId = tab.id;
        // add tabs/page info to hash array
        hashUris.push({hash: tab.hash, pageId: tab.pageId, tabIndex: i, tabId: tab.id, priActive: priTabId == tab.id});
        // initial page to be loaded
        if (priTabId == tab.id) priTabIndex = i;
        // current hash
        if (location.hash && '#'+tab.hash == location.hash) activeTabIndex = i;
    });
    if (!location.hash && !actPage && typeof priTabIndex != 'undefined') {
        // page load, load primary tab
        loadTabPage(priTabIndex);
    } else if (location.hash && !actPage && typeof activeTabIndex != 'undefined') {
        // page refresh
        loadTabPage(activeTabIndex);
    }
    $(window).hashchange( function(){
        if (location.hash) {
            $.each(hashUris, function(index, hashUri) {
                if ('#'+hashUri.hash == location.hash && actPage != hashUri.pageId + '#' + hashUri.hash) {
                    // found matching tab/page
                    loadTabPage(hashUri.tabIndex);
                }
            });
        } else if (actPage) {
            // navigated to empty space, attempt to find a primary active page
            $.each(hashUris, function(index, hashUri) {
                if (hashUri.priActive) loadTabPage(hashUri.tabIndex);
            });
        }
    });
});
function loadTabPage(tabIndex) {
    if (typeof tabSet[tabIndex] == 'undefined') return;

    // track when the page was loaded
    lastLoad = tabSet[tabIndex].lastLoad;
    tabSet[tabIndex].lastLoad = new Date().getTime();
    // load only once in 1ms-100ms
    if (tabSet[tabIndex].lastLoad - lastLoad < 100) return;

    // load page content/do actions here
    alert(tabSet[tabIndex].pageId);
    //$("#content").load('?pageId='+tabSet[tabIndex].pageId);

    // active page checked against hash during hashchange
    actPage = tabSet[tabIndex].pageId + '#' + tabSet[tabIndex].hash;
};
// user code to create tabs 
$(function() {
    // use tabs array to display some tabs
    // this depends on the above code to set .tabIndex on the tabSet array
    tabsObj = $('<div/>');
    $.each(tabSet, function(i, tab) {
        if (!tab.hash) return true;
        tmpObj = $('<span>'+tab.hash+'</span>');
        tmpObj.data('tabIndex', tab.tabIndex);

        // use an onclick event to change the page
        tmpObj.bind('click', function(e) {
            if (typeof $(this).data('tabIndex') == 'undefined' || typeof tabSet[$(this).data('tabIndex')] == 'undefined') return;

            // load page directly if active hash, otherwise change to clicked hash
            if ('#'+tabSet[$(this).data('tabIndex')].hash == location.hash) {
                loadTabPage($(this).data('tabIndex'));
            } else {
                location.hash = tabSet[$(this).data('tabIndex')].hash;
            }
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        });
        tmpObj.appendTo(tabsObj);
        delete tmpObj;
    });
    tabsObj.appendTo($("#tabs"));
    delete tabsObj;
});
</script>
<div id="tabs"><a href="#page1" >Link to Hash</a></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: The delay doesn't have anything to do with Bootstrap.  The delay is with Internet Explorer recognizing that the URL hash has changed.  You can observe this effect with nothing more than basic Javascript.

Comment: Can you provide me an example on how to reproduce the delay in internet explorer.  I've been unable to reproduce any delay/problems when listening for hashchange events in Internet Explorer 9 (x64).

Comment: I've more or less solved the issue by using cookies (in addition to the hash).

Upon further investigation, I've noticed that the problem isn't *always* easily reproduced.  It almost seems that with more and more Javascript in the page, IE is lagging behind on updating the value of `window.location.hash`, at least when it's being set from `window.location.replace`.

Answer (score 0):

Just experienced this problem for some clients who run IE8. We have a web page running sammy.js + knockout and bootstrap. Each route (link with hash) took about 800-900 ms to navigate to. However when i removed ALL css/styles from the page each route navigation took ~30 ms.